# how do I restore the network applet to the mate panel in bionic?

Tags: indicator, mate, panel, ubuntu-mate

how do I restore the network applet to the mate panel in bionic?
I recently upgraded Ubuntu Mate to the bionic version, and at some point the  default network applet as vanished from its top right panel abode.

How do I get it back to its proper estate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to restore in from MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`) by resetting panels layout:

[image: MATE Tweak]

Open *Panel* tab and try to switch panel layouts from for example *Familiar* to *Traditional*.

Also you can try to kill nm-applet and launch it again with:

```
killall nm-applet
nohup nm-applet &
```

Comment: Cool tool, I saved my current settings, and tried some others. when I returned to my original settings the "indicator applet complete" was back, so I'm happy. thanks for the pro-tips.